# gcc undefined reference to with pthread

Tags: gcc

I've been working with examples of csapp 3rd edition, and I couldn't successfully compile given codes from csapp website with gcc.

The source code I've tried to compile was "signal1.c" which includes header file "csapp.h" split into source code "csapp.c".

I've been trying to compile "signal1.c" in several ways like
"gcc csapp.h csapp.c signal1.c -o signal1"
"gcc csapp.c signal1.c -o signal1"

but only error message says

/tmp/ccGJtkct.o: In function `Pthread_create':
csapp.c:(.text+0x108a): undefined reference to`pthread_create'
/tmp/ccGJtkct.o: In function `Pthread_cancel':
csapp.c:(.text+0x10bd): undefined reference to`pthread_cancel'
/tmp/ccGJtkct.o: In function `Pthread_join':
csapp.c:(.text+0x10fb): undefined reference to`pthread_join'
/tmp/ccGJtkct.o: In function `Pthread_detach':
csapp.c:(.text+0x112e): undefined reference to`pthread_detach'
/tmp/ccGJtkct.o: In function `Pthread_once':
csapp.c:(.text+0x118f): undefined reference to`pthread_once'
/tmp/ccGJtkct.o: In function `Sem_init':
csapp.c:(.text+0x11b8): undefined reference to`sem_init'
/tmp/ccGJtkct.o: In function `P':
csapp.c:(.text+0x11e1): undefined reference to`sem_wait'
/tmp/ccGJtkct.o: In function `V':
csapp.c:(.text+0x120a): undefined reference to`sem_post'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've checked if header file "csapp.h" doesn't include  nor my computer doesn't have  with it but it doesn't seem so.

What will be of right choice to compile this?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've figured out yesterday that though <pthread.h> is inside standard library, I still need to link it in order to compile the signal1.
I tried "gcc -pthread -o csapp.c signal1.c" and this worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. `pthreads.h` is not and never has been a [C Standard library header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header),
and you do not link header files; you link the library for which a header file declares an API.